# "Toggling" Salesforce User Licenses?

Tags: user-management, userlicense

We had some old admins accidentally move some data around and it changed the values in a User Lookup on one of our custom objects.

I can recover the history of the field, but a lot of the users are no longer with the company and have been deactivated.

I have a solution that would re-activate a user, re-assign the records and then deactivate the user in a single script. But I want to confirm that as long as I do this User by User and stay under our license count I won't be billed for the users I toggle on and off.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good. As long as you stay under your license count you're fine. SFDC won't allow you to exceed the limit

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reactive the users, with [Audit Fields and Update Records with Inactive Owners](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227663&type=1) checked, admins can **update owner and sharing-based fields on records with inactive owners**. UI won't let you to select inactive user, you have to use data loader or any other tool.